# RAID controller "Unexpected sense: PD ..."

Tags: hard-drive, raid, error-logging

I have an LSI 9270CV-8i RAID controller I just installed a few days ago. I finally got around to initializing the disks I had connected. I set up a simple virtual disk made of 2 disks in RAID-0.

When I tell the system to initialize the disks the log in the MegaRAID storage manager begins to fill up with this.

```
ID = 113
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 596
TIME = 18-05-2017 20:48:30
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0   Unexpected sense:   PD       =   
Port 0 - 3:0:0Power on, reset, or bus device reset occurred,   CDB   =    0x1b 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00    ,   Sense   =    0x70 0x00 0x06 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x0a 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x29 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00

ID = 113
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 595
TIME = 18-05-2017 20:48:29
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0   Unexpected sense:   PD       =   
Port 0 - 3:0:0Power on, reset, or bus device reset occurred,   CDB   =    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00    ,   Sense   =    0x70 0x00 0x06 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x0a 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x29 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00

ID = 113
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 594
TIME = 18-05-2017 20:48:19
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0   Unexpected sense:   PD       =   
Port 0 - 3:0:0Power on, reset, or bus device reset occurred,   CDB   =    0x8a 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0xf7 0x82 0x00 0x00 0x03 0xff 0x00 0x00    ,   Sense   =    0x70 0x00 0x06 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x0a 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x29 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00

ID = 113
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 593
TIME = 18-05-2017 20:48:18
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0   Unexpected sense:   PD       =   
Port 0 - 3:0:0Power on, reset, or bus device reset occurred,   CDB   =    0x8a 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0xa3 0x97 0x00 0x00 0x03 0xff 0x00 0x00    ,   Sense   =    0x70 0x00 0x06 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x0a 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x29 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

After reading a few forums and such it had mentioned its a sign that a disk on the array is failing. Based on the device address I was able to narrow it down to disk 0 in the pair. When I placed disk 0 in a virtual disk group by itself I was able to reproduce the errors.

What I find very odd thought is the drive passes both SMART and surface tests with the HGST WinDFT suite (the drive is HGST). So the card says the drive is bad but it tests fine.

The to throw another wrench into the puzzle I found this forum post on Dell talking about how it might not be a problem at all.
[Dell Forum](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/906/t/19603109)

Can anyone shed some light on this for me? I am already going to get an RMA for the drive but I will cancel it if the drive is fine.